# What is the significance of array with zero "[0]" in this javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This code is used to filter the true values, I don't understand why that last array with zero is being used.

```
const rand = [{ inputNumber }, { inputBig }, { inputSmall }, { inputSymbol }]
  .filter(value => Object.values(value)[0])
```

Comment: Because it takes the first value of the object. Since the objects have a single value, it's also the first value.

Comment: The logic in filter will also have no effect at all, so that call is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan [it will filer out any objects that have zero or falsy values](https://jsbin.com/qosoyes/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ ah, thanks. Every day's a school day :)

Comment: It definitely means the array with zero does not does not recognize zero and false as a value..

Comment: That's not an array, that's a property access

Comment: @ASDFGerte, can you expatiate further?

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), it's basic javascript syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That notation may be used to avoid to have to parse values when you need to remove symbols like quotation marks.